# R: use a loop to apply a formula using 2 variables from different datasets

Tags: r, loops, nested, formula

I have two Excel sheets of climate data: temperature (dtT) and relative humidity (dtR).  Each frame is 39 rows (monitoring sites) by 64 columns (61 days numbered from 121 to 181, "lat", "lon", and "county"). Both sheets are in the exact same order. I want to use these two datasets to calculate the "heat index" for each monitoring site on each day, filling up another dataframe of the same dimensions.

PROBLEM: I am attempting to use a nested loop, but all the values come back as zeros.  Could it be that because the "county" column contains words, R is reading all the numbers as characters, and so it can't perform the calculations?  (**The columns specified may appear confusing here but i'm looking for general strategy)

```
dtT <- read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/Tavg3.csv")
dtR <- read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/RHavg3.csv")    
# Make a new data frame
hi = cbind(dtT, dtR)
# Add empty columns for heat index
hi[paste("hi",121:181,sep="")] = 0  
# Loop to fill each hi cell using NOAA formula
for(i in 1:length(hi$lat)){
    t <- hi[i, 3:63]
    r <- hi[i, 64:124]
    h <- hi[i, 125:185]
    for(j in 1:length(t)){
        h[i,j] = -42.379 + (2.04901523*t[j]) + (10.14333127*r[j]) - (0.22475541*t[j]*r[j]) - 
                ((6.83783*10^-3)*(t[j]^2)) - ((5.481717*10^-2)*(r[j]^2) ) + ((1.22874*10^3) - (t[j]^2)*r[j]) + ((8.5282*10^-4)*t[j]*(r[j]^2)) - ((1.99*10^-6)*(t[j]^2)*(r[j]^2))
    }
}
hi[1:10, 130:140]
hi = hi[,c(1:2, 125:185]
```

Comment: What "county" column???? If you are not going to post a minimal example, then at least post enough of the `str()` output on 'dtT' and 'dtR' to make some sense of your question.

Comment: My apologies- I was thinking I was weeding out unnecessary information but I see now that I didn't give the whole picture.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you update `h[i,j]`, but afterwards you look at `hi`... What does `h` look like after the for-loop?

Note that modifying `h` will **not** modify `hi` even though conceptually `h` is a subset of `hi`...

You could probably just replace `h[i,j] =` with `hi[i,j+124] =`

Comment: This fixes it- thanks!  I didn't understand that subtlety of the difference b/w hi and h : )

Comment: About the hi[i, j+124]... why 124?  If each set has 61 days then aren't they only 122 apart?

Comment: Well, for h you extracted columns 125 onward from hi. Since i starts at 1, 124+1 is 125...

Answer (score 2):

If the data.frames have exactly the same size, columns, rows, 
you can extract the numeric values, as a matrix,
and do the computations on those two matrices.

```
temperature <- as.matrix(dtT[,4:64]) # Use the correct column numbers
humidity    <- as.matrix(dtR[,4:64])
heat_index <- 
  -42.379 + 
  2.04901523  * temperature + 
  10.14333127 * humidity - 
  0.22475541  * temperature * humidity - 
  6.83783e-3  * temperature^2 - 
  5.481717e-2 * humidity^2 + 
  1.22874e3   * temperature^2 * humidity + 
  8.5282e-4   * temperature * humidity^2 - 
  1.99e-6     * temperature^2 * humidity^2
# Put back the latitude, longitude, county columns 
# (assuming they were the first three)
cbind( dtT[,1:3], heat_index )
```

Comment: Wow I love this solution- thank you!  It really depicts the formula very cleanly.  I am going to run both this and the edit given by @Tommy and cross check the results.